# Multiplication of vectors of matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I had the problem that I need to multiply a vector with a vector of spin matrices in python.

```
d=np.array([a,b,c]) \
sigma=np.array([sigma_x,sigma_y,sigma_z])\
print(d ? sigma)
```

where a,b and c are complex numbers, sigma_xi are the Pauli matrices, and ? is to be understood as a placeholder for the correct dot product. I am aware that there are numpy functions like dot, matmul, tensordot(..., axis=n) and so on, but they all don't produce the result that I need.

First problem: The entries of d are scalar, while those of sigma are matrices.
This can be fixed by defining d as

```
d=np.array([a * sigma_0,b * sigma_0,c * sigma_0])
```

where sigma_0 are 2x2 unit matrices. But the problem remains. There is no function that multiplies that properly.

Comment: You can probably do this without iteration, can you post some sample data?

Comment: How about `d[:,None,None]*sigma`?  I don't think you need matrix multiplication here, do you?  Just multiply the elements of `d` by the corresponding elements of `sigma`.  The result should be a (3,2,2) array.

Comment: The vector d contains 2x2 matrices multiplied with scalar values dx,dy,dz. Yes, it is a (3,2,2) array. Can you explain why your `d[:,None,None]*sigma` works? I do not understand the interaction between the None,None part and a 2x2 array. What kind of array (3,?,?) is d when defined with the "None"s?
Thanks for the answer in any case. That's a nice shortcut.

Comment: @hpaulj I assume then, the function I defined below can also be substituted with some clever indexing. Though, I wouldn't understand how. I do not really get the logic behind it. As you can maybe tell, I'm not a programmer. I just understand what math I need python to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem can be easily solved by a self defined function, I just wanted to provide it here.

```
def vmdot(a,b): #vectormatrixdot
    result=0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        result+=a[i].dot(b[i])
    return result
```

Not really a braintwister, but I ended up googling anyways, and judging from existing posts, others end up googling too. Might save people some time. Hope this post doesn't bother anybody.

Comment: What are the dimensions of `a` and `b`?

Comment: These are now two (3,2,2) objects. They are vectors of Pauli matrices, eg (ox,oy,oz). If i calculate (ox,oy,oz)*(ox,oy,oz), i expect the result to be (ox,oy,oz)*(ox,oy,oz)=ox^2+oy^2+oz^2 which is a 2x2-matrix, which is what the function calculates. a.dot(b) gave me the correct matrix multiplication, when testing it.

Comment: `a@b` produces a (3,2,2) matrix product - using the first dimension, 3, as the 'batch'.  Looks like you want to add a sum on that dimension, `np.sum(a@b, axis=0)` to make a (2,2)

Comment: Will try it out. Thank you.